# Excel: removing formulas but keeping the answers as text

Tags: excel

I have an Excel document which makes a lot of calculations and shows the results in specific fields as text. I need to get these answers into PHP but Excel Reader can't read those fields, since they are the results of calculations.

So, I want to save the Excel document without the formulas/calculations, but with the results as text. How do i do this?

I'm stuck using Excel 2004 Mac btw.

edit: I forgot to mention: a client of mine has to upload a new version of this Excel document each day (the calculations change daily), so the simpler the solution the better. Also, there are too many values to change them all manually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A finger dance worth remembering

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>

To Paste Special (Values)

Comment: or record a macro for the purpose and bind it to Ctrl-[SomeKey]

Comment: You can select multiple sheets and use this answer for higher productivity.

Also save as .csv (and open again) works (for single sheet).

Answer (score 7):

select all, then copy, then paste special as value

if this is need every day then you almost certainly want to record a macro that loops over very worksheet in the work book and does this